# How can I merge and flatten a Spark DataFrame with a DataFrame returned by a function *for each row*

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

### Basic Setup

I have built a word2vec model in spark using the built in Word2Vec spark ml Estimator

```
val df = ...

val word2Vec = new Word2Vec().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("w2v").setNumPartitions(16)
val word2VecModel = word2Vec.fit(df)
```

I am able to see the vocabulary and the corresponding vectors by invoking `word2VecModel.getVectors`:

```
scala> word2VecModel.getVectors.show()
+-------------+--------------------+
|         word|              vector|
+-------------+--------------------+
|          cpu|[0.00346526037901...|
|       memory|[0.00856703612953...|
|     computer|[-0.0730776190757...|
...
```

I am also able to see the synonyms for words in the vocabulary:

```
scala> word2VecModel.findSynonyms("computer", 10).show()
+----------------+------------------+
|            word|        similarity|
+----------------+------------------+
|         monitor|0.9808058738708496|
|         printer|0.9771893620491028|
|        keyboard|0.9753882884979248|
...
```

I now need to iterate through all the words in the vocabulary, find the top 10 synonyms for each word and export that information so that it can be used by an external application.  I'm basically trying to build a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+
|word|        word2|        similarity|
+----+-------------+------------------+
|cpu |        word2|0.7599380612373352|
|cpu |        word3| 0.710058867931366|
|cpu |        word4|0.7066144943237305|
|ram |        word5|0.7066144943237305|
...
```

### First Attempt

I tried using a simple UDF like this:

```
val func = udf((vector: Vector) => {word2VecModel.findSynonyms(vector, 10)})
word2VecModel.getVectors.withColumn("synonyms", col("word"))
```

but that returns the error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] is not supported
```

### Second Attempt

I managed to get a version working using a UDF, however it's *extremely* slow (>12 hours on a smallish dataset), and uses a `.collect()` to convert the DataFrame returned by `word2VecModel.findSynonyms` into an Array which I understand is also not best practice.

```
implicit val caseEncoder: Encoder[Word2VecSimilarity] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Word2VecSimilarity]

val extractWordSimilaritiesIntoArray = udf { word: String =>
  word2VecModel.findSynonyms(word, 10).map ({ row =>
    Word2VecSimilarity(row.getAs(0), row.getAs(1))
  })(caseEncoder).collect()
}
```

### Question

Is there a way to merge the first DataFrame of vocabulary words and vectors (`word2VecModel.getVectors`) with a the dataFrame of `word2VecModel.findSynonyms(word, 10)` *for each row* in a performant, distributed way so that I can build a flattened dataFrame for export?